# Android LinearLayout getChildAt(index)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

`LinearLayout` `getChildAt(index)` method always returning 0th position of child view. How to get remain child views in my `LinearLayout` by `getChildAt(index)`.

Any help .Thanks

Comment: you are using only linearlayout or any listview.

Comment: why don't you post your code.

Comment: only linearlayout. It has 4 child views. I am trying to access all child views. but that method returning only 0th position child view

Comment: try my answer and see any benefit..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

may be it can help you.

ll is your linear layout here.

```
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
}
```